# What happens when you call free(var) after malloc in C?

Tags: c

I have a function which must be called multiple times and contain a string I have allocated using malloc. The first call to the function works fine, but the second call it appears that the first string was never "deleted" from memory. I had always thought that the "free" keyword meant it would completely free up the memory it was allocated to on the heap. What is free actually doing?

Comment: `malloc` and `free` manage a "pool" of available memory.  Precisely how they do that is up to the implementation.  Calling `free` simply means that you are giving some memory back to the pool, and promising that you're done with it, that you won't try to use it any more.  Any further details are dependent on your specific implementation and shouldn't matter.  And any diagnosis of a problem you think you're seeing will require that you show us your actual code!

Comment: Share some code and errors which were occurred

Comment: If you say something like `char *p = malloc(10); strcpy(p, "Hello"); printf("%s\n", p); free(p); printf("%s\n", p);`, it's likely to print `Hello` twice.  But that does **not** mean that `free` did nothing!  Calling `free` does not clear or destroy the memory, it just says, "This memory is available, because I'm not using it any more."  But you broke that promise if you printed it again after freeing.

Comment: `malloc` and `free` allocate and free memory. They don't "delete" anything.

Comment: If you want memory initialized to 0 use `calloc`

Comment: Not a dup, but this may be relevant: [Is free() zeroing out memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683519)

Comment: See also [this classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794).  (It's not talking about `malloc` and `free`, but it might as well be.)

Comment: There were 2 different questions with exactly the same title (but different content) in the last hour. And 5 hours ago, there were 4 different questions about `free` - all 4 questions also had exactly the same title but a different one than these 3 questions. Was there a university lecture about `malloc` and `free` today?

Answer (score 2):

C 2018 7.22.3.3 2 says, of `free(ptr)`:

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined.

That is all. It makes memory available for further allocation (the memory management software updates its records to note the memory is available for new uses). It is not required to change the memory (nor is it required not to change the memory), and it does not change `ptr` (although the “value” of `ptr` becomes invalid in C’s semantics).

Answer (score 2):

The C library function `void free(void *ptr)` de-allocates the heap memory previously allocated by a call to `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc`.

For an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t my_data_length = 10;
    int *my_data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * my_data_length);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < my_data_length; i++)
        my_data[i] = i * i;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < my_data_length; i++)
        printf("%d\n", my_data[i]);
    free(my_data);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code generates squares from 0 to 10, `10` is not included.
So, I used `free` to de-allocate the heap memory I have used to store `my_data`.

If I didn't wrote `free(my_data);`, then also output would be same but under the hood some memory leaks will happen (modern OS manages the memory itself whenever a program exits without freeing its heap allocated memory).

For an example:

If I debug this code under `valgrind`, the output will be like this:

```
==29666== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29666==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29666==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 4,136 bytes allocated
==29666== 
==29666== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29666== 
==29666== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Now, if I remove that `free` line then `valgrind's` output will be:

```
==29719== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29719==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==29719==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 4,136 bytes allocated
==29719== 
==29719== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==29719== Checked 114,288 bytes
==29719== 
==29719== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==29719==    at 0x4845899: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29719==    by 0x109168: main (main.c:7)
==29719== 
==29719== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29719==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==29719==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719== 
==29719== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Which clearly indicates that a block of heap memory was not freed while exiting the application.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when you call ... `malloc` in C?

Let's look at a computer without MMU (on modern desktop computers, it is a bit more complicated):

There is some memory area called the "heap". You might imagine this "heap" as array of `char`:

```
char heap[10000];
```

This array is used for the data allocated by `malloc`.

When you call `malloc(200)`, the operating system checks which range in the array with the requested size is currently not used. Let's say the range from `heap[400]` to `heap[599]` is currently not in use.

Then the operating system stores the following information somewhere:

- The range 400...599 is no longer unused but used
- The range starting at `heap[400]` is 200 bytes long

Then it returns the pointer `&(heap[400])` (this is the value returned by `malloc`).

> What happens when you call `free(var)` ... in C?

Let's say `var=&(heap[400])`.

The operating system reads the information that the range starting at `heap[400]` is 200 bytes long. (This information was stored during `malloc`.)

Then it stores the information that the range 400...599 is now free and can be used for future calls of `malloc`.

> ... but the second call it appears that the first string was never "deleted" from memory.

The operating system has only stored the information that the area from `heap[400]` to `heap[599]` is unused so it can be used in future calls of `malloc`.

Unless a special security variant of `malloc` or `free` is used, the values of these 200 bytes are not overwritten.

And after you called `free(var)`, `var` will still point to `heap[400]` (assuming a computer without MMU)!

When you call `malloc` again with the same size (and no other program has called `malloc` in the meantime), it is very probable that the OS will find out that the range from `heap[400]` to `heap[599]` is free and return a pointer to `heap[400]`.

And this range still contains your string (if no other program called `malloc` in the meantime) because it was not overwritten.

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question, malloc is short for memory allocation because it does exactly that: it claims a chunk of memory for itself even if it is not currently using it. This makes sure that other apps don't use that memory every time your app pauses for a moment. When you allocate a megabyte of memory, the Task Manager will say that your app is using 1 megabyte of RAM, even if it does not use the memory it allocated at all. When you free() that memory, it gives it back to the operating system to allow other apps to use it.

Aside from the technical stuff, it sounds like you are trying to increase of decrease the amount of RAM that is available to your variable. To do that, use realloc(). For example:

```
char *x = malloc(50);

/*
Now your program will determine that you need to reallocate x to a new size.
This could be because the computer has run out of memory, or the 
variable you originally planned on placing in x has increased in size.
*/

x = realloc(x, 25);
```

realloc() is different from free() + malloc() because it preserves the original value of your variable.

A variable declared in a function will automatically be freed at the end of that function, and likewise with functions declared in if-else, loops, or any  kind of code wrapped around curly braces `{ }`. The reason you may need to use free() is incase you need to either:

1. Free up memory space that your program no longer needs.
2. Re-purpose your variable to something else by freeing it and allocating it again (which is different from realloc()ing a variable because realloc preserves the original value of the variable)